# Association of foreign key to a table in different schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Can anyone please tell me how can we create links and association for two tables in different schemas in ADF application, i am using jdeveloper 12c .

thanks in advance .

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: We have two schemas , schema one for employee details and second one is for attendance details , we don't want to duplicate employee data and we want to access employee data through employee id and relate tables through foreign key

Answer (score 0):

To access tables of a different schema (user) you need to grant select for that schema. 
I have no idea how to do that with Jdeveloper IDE (never used it), but perhaps try doing it using SQLDeveloper and see how Jdeveloper reacts..:

So log in to the schema that already has the user table and then

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE yourusertable TO theotherschema
```

Perhaps after that you can see the table in Jdeveloper and you can create a FK reference on the table as usual.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, well we have already given grant on table from one schema to another however we are unable to create association and links in Jdeveloper for linking those tables.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps that helped me.

1. In JDeveloper click on the offline database schema that needs to see the other offline database schema. All the schemas are immediately under the folder icon, "Offline Database Sources".
2. Right mouse click and select "Properties...". It's the last option on the Context Menu.
3. A popup window titled, "Edit Offline Database" will appear. Select "Dependencies" on the left list and click on the + icon circled in red as shown in 
   [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5KNy.png).
4. Select from the list of available schemas and you are done. It should be possible to reference tables from the other schema when adding foreign keys in the current schema from JDeveloper.